# Entity Framework: One<->Many<->One Mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a one to many relationship mapped with the EF and for some reason it's proving more difficult than usual. This is my EDMX and DB Schema. The reason I used an auto-increment key on the middle table is because I was told it's difficult to use composite keys with the EF.

What I need is to be able to do (with a Course entity) someCourse.Students or (with a student entity) someStudent.Courses. Could anyone give me some pointers as to the best way of mapping this?

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4053/schemacz.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4053/schemacz.png)
[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8193/edmx.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8193/edmx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the AssociationID column and make both the StudentID and CourseID the primary key of the StudentCourses table, it will pick up the many-to-many relationship and generate more intuitive entity classes (ie Student.Courses, Course.Students)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.

One problem though, I'm having problems deleting a student from a course or vice versa. I can get the data out of the entity no problem, but when I come to save changes nothing is persisted. Eg:

   var requestedCourse = context.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseID == CourseId).FirstOrDefault();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(student.Courses.Count); // 0
   student.Courses.Remove(requestedCourse);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(student.Courses.Count); // still 0

Comment: Turns out an Include("Courses") was needed to allow the course to be deleted.